# How to catch System.exit() code within a huge Java project?

Tags: java, findbugs, system.exit

I am getting into a project which needs some automated review tools. Last week we found some `System.exit()` in the code which brought down the app servers.

It appears that FindBugs does not catch `System.exit()`. Are there any other tools which can catch `System.exit()` as well which I can run from eclipse?

Comment: @Tom, that will take care of the low hanging fruit, but it won't catch any invocation through reflection. Also, you need to also check for `Runtime.getRuntime().exit(int)`.

Comment: Eclipse can also search for methods though that won’t help with reflection, either.

Comment: @Dilum Ranatunga There are certainly other patterns you could grep for to find bad code. Notable here `Runtime.getRuntime` and `java.lang.reflect`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about setting up a security manager that prevents anything not white-listed from calling `System.exit()`? I imagine your application server has a security manager; look into the security policy. If you are rolling out your own, look at [`checkExit(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#checkExit%28int%29)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using pmd in addition to findbugs?  PMD 'compiles' the java code to xml and runs xpath queries against it.

For example:

```
//VariableDeclarator
[parent::FieldDeclaration]
[../Type/ReferenceType
  /ClassOrInterfaceType[@Image='SimpleDateFormat']
  and
  ..[@Static = 'true'] ]
```

is a rule to identify a statically defined SimpleDateFormat object (something that could be used in a thread unsafe way).